# How to plot a histogram of a Column 'Applicant_Income' based on a condition of other column 'Education"?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have a csv file with columns `'Applicant_Income`' and `'Education'`. I can plot the 'Applicant_Income' but how do i plot a hist of `'Applicant_Income'` where `'Education' = 'Graduate'`.

I tried the something in boxplot, would like something similar on histogram.

```
g1=df.boxplot('ApplicantIncome', by = 'Education')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try to supply a [Minimal Complete Working Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing your data, what you have tried so far, and what you would like to achieve. For me it is not clear if you want to plot *only* the data where `'Education' == 'Graduate'`, or *all* data, but *grouped by* `'Education'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, you will want to use `plt.hist` for histograms. From your question it's not completely clear whether you want to filter the data (`'Education' == 'Graduate'`) or plot a single histogram for every group in `Education`.

Lets's generate example data

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ApplicantIncome': np.random.normal(500, 2000, 500),
                   'Education': np.random.choice(['Graduate', 'High School', 'Undergrad'], 500)})


    ApplicantIncome Education
0   617.660998      Undergrad
1   1335.209849     Graduate
2   -966.902454     Undergrad
3   1775.496777     High School
4   -819.677673     Undergrad
```

Now if you just want to plot the filtered data:

```
df_grad = df[df['Education'] == 'Graduate']
plt.hist(df_grad['ApplicantIncome'])
```

If you want to plot one histogram for each education status:

```
for name, group in df.groupby('Education'):
    plt.hist(group['ApplicantIncome'], label=name)
```